# Transform a pair of int list to boolean matrix in OCaml

Tags: debugging, matrix, boolean, ocaml

I have a function that taking `(int * int list) list` to a boolean matrix. I tested with my counter example and it gave me a correct answer. Like code below.

```
let to_matrix l =
let n = List.length l in
  let m = Array.make_matrix (n + 1) (n + 1) false in
  List.iter (fun (i, j) ->
  List.iter (fun t ->
    m.(i).(t) <- true) j) l;
  m;;

let ex = to_matrix [(0, [1; 0]); (1, [0]); (2, [1])];;
```

It gives me a matrix:

```
true true false false  
true false false false  
false true false false  
false false false false
```

I have to test it in my real data, it is an xsds list, like data script below. For example:

```
[Elt ("name", Some (SimpleType "string"), 1, Bound 1);
   Group ("label",
    Some
     (Choice
       [Elt ("numberLabel",
         Some
          (Sequence
            [Elt ("number", Some (SimpleType "nonNegativeInteger"), 0,
              Unbounded)]),
         1, Bound 1);
        Elt ("symbolLabel",
         Some (Sequence [GroupRef ("name", 0, Unbounded)]), 1, Bound 1)]),
    1, Bound 1)]
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answer from Thomas.

I missed the explanation about the type I returned from traverse these trees.

The type after traverse it look like this list:

[("name"; ["string"]); ("label"; ["nonNegativeInteger"; "name"])...]

From this xsds list I would like to represent an boolean matrix to show the dependence between them, for example: type name depend on type string; type
label depend on type nonNegativeInteger and name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `to_matrix` is wrong.

You can see it if you test it with `to_matrix [(0, [2])];;`

In order to make it work, you need to find a way to map the `'a` of your list to `[0..(n-1)]` where `n` is the number of elements appearing in your list.

A possible way it to use an association list:

```
let mapping = ref []
let int_of_a a =
  if List.mem_assq a !mapping then
    List.assq a !mapping
  else
    let n = List.length !mapping in
    mapping := (a, n) :: !mapping;
    n
```

and to change your `to_matrix` function to be:

```
let to_matrix l =
  (* step 1: registering your inputs *)
  mapping := [];
  let register i = ignore (int_of_a i) in
  List.iter (fun (i, j) ->
    register i;
    List.iter register j
  ) l;
  let n = List.length !mapping in
  (* step 2: creating and populating your matrix *)
  let m = Array.make_matrix n n false in
    List.iter (fun (i, j) ->
      List.iter (fun t ->
        m.(int_of_a i).(int_of_a t) <- true
      ) j
    ) l;
    m;;
```

That's clearly not the best way to write this kind of things, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way I can take my xsd list  without split my xsd list to (int * int list) list to matrx ? Is it possible to split my xsd list? because in my result when I tested with my data, it always taking a position like [(0; (0, 1); (1; (0; 1))], I don't know how can I get a right position and return a right connection between them, for example: "label" has a connection with "name", where label has a position 1, and name has a position of a name (0) in a list, not starting a new position in a list. What I want is that I can show a relationship dependent between them.

Comment: `mapping` contains the association you want